# Can a character use VR to block noise which prevents her from sleeping?

Tags: shadowrun

A group of PCs is bound to stay in a noisy location for some time, with a noise level and/or type which would normally prohibit sleeping, such as sudden, short bursts of noise (e.g. gun fire, loud vehicles).

Could characters capable of accessing Virtual Reality use this to block the noise and get sleep? I am aware that this would make them prone to sneak attacks, but implementing some wake-up pulse from inside the Matrix using a PAN-attached device seems quite possible to me.

Comment: You'd be amazed at what people can learn to sleep through.  People sleep next to train tracks with trains passing by irregularly, and in warzones with intermittent weapons-fire and bombings.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

### VR Sleeping

a) This is super cool.  A character in a loud place 'jacks in', goes to her personal VR meditation space, and falls asleep?  That's super cool.  That's cyberpunk as hell.  That's utterly worthy.  Even if the rules didn't support it, I would instantly allow it.

b) The rules allow for this perfectly.  While in VR, you are unaware of your surroundings.  You could sleep while in VR - nothing says you can't, and it makes sense from how VR is described.

c) I cannot reiterate enough how cool this is.

Comment: Ad b. RAW actually says that's not possible - you are kicked back to AR if you fall unconcious, unless you're link-locked (and link-locking yourself before going to sleep is something you probably shouldn't consider).

Agree with points a and c though :)

Comment: Unconsciousness is not the same thing as sleep.  Not to mention that an individual who fell asleep to be moved to AR wouldn't need to stay in VR necessarily to sleep.

Comment: @Attackfarm: the question would be whether manufacturers made the distinction. Sleep is an altered state of consciousness. Perhaps the unconsciousness dump is a failsafe. One would expect the same failsafe to be present for sleep... Who wants a sleeping database admin to delete data in their sleep?

Comment: @decPL you can turn off  or bypass most of those safety features (though, as you mention, doing so is often a bad idea).  Also, there's a clear distinction made between unconsciousness and an altered state of conciousness: you don't stop being able to use the Matrix when you're high, and going to sleep certainly isn't a bigger change than taking LSD. Dump happens on knockout only, omae.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I specifically said **by RAW**. Otherwise it's your game, play it however you want - I sure do :)

Comment: @decPL  ...I'm talking about the RAW.  Whatever, this isn't the place for discussion.